# Ansible register variable not defined

Tags: ansible

Before running a patching playbook, I ran the playbook with the "--check" option as a dry run. However, one of the plays within the playbook to check whether the group needs a reboot, doesn't register the "reboot_hint" variable as intended

```
- name: check for reboot
  shell: needs-restarting -r
  register: reboot_hint
  failed_when: reboot_hint.rc > 1

- name: debug, show the reboot hint variable
  debug:
    var:
       - reboot_hint.rc
       - reboot_hint
```

I get the message: ""VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"" for the run.
What could be causing this? I am expect a return value of "1" or "0". I do get that when I go into the command line, run the "needs-restarting -r" and "echo $?

```
No core libraries or services have been updated.
Reboot is probably not necessary.
> echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 3):

You're running `--check` and thus the shell command doesn't run. Because the shell command doesn't run there's nothing to register.

You can read more about this in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#enabling-or-disabling-check-mode-for-tasks

A simple fix is adding `check_mode: no`, e.g.

```
- name: check for reboot
  check_mode: no
  shell: needs-restarting -r
  register: reboot_hint
  failed_when: reboot_hint.rc > 1
```

This forces the task to run even when check-mode is enabled.

Comment: Note that for idempotence, you should also add `changed_when: false` since the command is purely informative and will never change the system. shell/command always returns "changed" by default whenever command succeeds.